# Not being able to sort my html list on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I've been working on a simple code that would detect how many clicks an item has received and it would put it on the top of the list, the problem is, I can only replace the first item once, if I clicked on it again it's doesn't add up the number of clicks inside of the items. Why is this?

***My code:*** (Ctrl + Shift + I) and inspect the `items` to see them change

```js
$(function() {
  $('.watchMe > .item').attr({
    "influence": "0"
  });
});
$('.watchMe > .item').mousedown(function() {
  $(this).attr({
    "influence": parseInt($(this).attr("influence"), 10) + 1
  });
});
$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  rearrangeEm();
});

function rearrangeEm() {
  var tempArray = [];
  $('.watchMe > .item').each(function() {
    tempArray.push([this, parseInt($(this).attr("influence"), 10)]);
    console.log(this);
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < tempArray.length; j++) {
      var temp;
      if (tempArray[i][1] < tempArray[j][1]) {
        temp = tempArray[i];
        tempArray[i] = tempArray[j];
        tempArray[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  $('.watchMe').empty();
  for (i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
    $('.watchMe').append(tempArray[i][0]);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>smartSystem</title>
  <style>
    .item {
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="watchMe">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're removing the original `.item` elements which have the `mousedown` event bound to them, so you need to use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$('.watchMe').on('mousedown', '> .item', function() {
  $(this).attr({
    "influence": parseInt($(this).attr("influence"), 10) + 1
  });
});
```

Note however, that you can both improve and shorten your logic using `data()` attributes (as opposed to a custom attribute which will make your HTML code invalid) and the `sort()` method. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.watchMe').on('mousedown', '> .item', function() {
    $(this).data('influence', ($(this).data('influence') || 0) + 1);
  });

  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    rearrangeEm();
  });
});

function rearrangeEm() {
  $('.watchMe > .item').sort(function(a, b) {
    var aInf = $(a).data('influence') || 0, bInf = $(b).data('influence') || 0;
    return aInf < bInf ? 1 : aInf > bInf ? -1 : 0;
  }).appendTo('.watchMe');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>smartSystem</title>
  <style>
    .item {
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="watchMe">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh that's tricky, I didn't know the events were actually bounded to the elements, Thank you so much Rory, you saved my as.. Life

Comment: Sorry for my probably dumb question which shows my lack of knowledge on jQuery, but what does $(this).data('influence') || 0 mean?  this or 0? if this is undefined/null then assign 0?

Comment: That's it exactly. You can use boolean type coercion to shortcut a default value for the variable.

Comment: Oh that's sweet, no more `unable to get value of 'undefined'`